# Excel VBA creating a Hyperlink to the same cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet with the string "Title" repeating several times in Column B. For each instance of Title I want to place a hyperlink to the same cell in the value a row directly under it (i.e. if title is in B1 I would like a hyperlink in B2).

So if the hyperlink was in B2 effectively it would do nothing but say on the same cell when clicked.

However, I need the exsting value in cell B2 to not change, all that will happen is it will go from a regular value to a hyperlinked value.

Below is what I have come up with thus far, keep in mind im pretty new to VBA so pointers are appreciated.

```
Sub RunThis()
    'Declare workbook and worksheets:
    Dim mainFile As Workbook, titleDetailSheet As Worksheet    
    Set mainFile = ActiveWorkbook    
    Set titleDetailSheet = mainFile.Sheets("Title Detail")
    Dim searchString As String

    searchString = "Title"

    For r = 1 To 200
        If titleDetailSheet.Range("B" & r) = searchString Then
            titleDetailSheet.Range("B" & r + 1) = **'ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add     Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:=titleDetailSheet.Name & "!A1", TextToDisplay:="Title"**
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

I'm not sure what the correct syntax would be for the bolded script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## HyperlinkBColumn

In

```
Set mainFile = ActiveWorbook
```

you misspelled Activeworkbook.

The part

```
SubAddress:=titleDetailSheet.Name & "!A1"
```

is a tricky one:

```
SubAddress:="'" & titleDetailSheet.Name & "'!A1"
```

Your variables are miles long. Try to shorten them.

```
Option Explicit
'With Project ==================================================================
'  .Title: HyperlinkBColumn
'  .Author: YMG
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'  With .Contents
'    Sub HyperlinkBColumn
'  End With
'===============================================================================
'
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub HyperlinkBColumn()
'
'Description:
'  Loops through a specified column and when a specified value is found, puts
'  a hyperlink in the cell below.
'Arguments
'  None
'Returns
'  Hyperlinks on worksheet, Debugging info in the Immediate Window
'
'--Customize BEGIN ---------------------
  Const cWsName As String = "Title Detail"
  Const cSearch As String = "Title"
   Const cRow1 As Integer = 1
      Const cRow2 As Long = 200
     Const cCol As String = "B"
  Const cHeader As String = "Processing rows..." 'Immdediate Window
  Const cFooter As String = "...finished processing." 'Immediate Window
'--Customize END -----------------------
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
  Dim oWb As Workbook
  Dim oWs As Worksheet
  Dim rCell1 As Range
  Dim rCell2 As Range
  Dim iR As Integer
  Dim strText As String
  Dim strAddr As String
  Dim str1 As String 'Immediate Window
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
  Set oWb = ActiveWorkbook
  Set oWs = oWb.Worksheets(cWsName)
  For iR = cRow1 To cRow2
    Set rCell1 = oWs.Range(cCol & iR)
    Set rCell2 = oWs.Range(cCol & iR + 1)
    strText = rCell2.Text 'What's written in the cell.
    strAddr = rCell2.Address 'The address e.g. B1, B13 ...
    If rCell1 = cSearch Then
      If strText <> "" Then
        'Anchor is the place where to put the hyperlink, cell or object.
        'Notice the single quotes (') in the SubAddress.
        'Readability is very important, notice every argument on its own line.
        'It's much easier to find a mistake.
        rCell2.Hyperlinks.Add _
        Anchor:=rCell2, _
        Address:="", _
        SubAddress:="'" & oWs.Name & "'!" & strAddr, _
        TextToDisplay:=strText 'The same text as requested
        str1 = str1 & vbCrLf & iR & ". " & rCell1.Address & " " _
          & strText & " - at " & strAddr 'Immediate Window
       Else
        'Put in here what to do if the cell below the Title cell is empty.
        'I've chosen to skip the line.
      End If
    End If
  Next
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    str1 = cHeader & str1 & vbCrLf & cFooter 'Immediate Window
    Debug.Print str1 'Immediate Window
'
End Sub
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'
'With Idea Source --------------------------------------------------------------
'  .Title: Excel VBA creating a Hyperlink to the same cell
'  .TitleURL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52527595/excel-vba-creating-a-hyperlink-to-the-same-cell
'  .Author: Nayan
'  .AuthorURL: https://stackoverflow.com/users/10416060/nayan
'End With ----------------------------------------------------------------------
'
'End With ======================================================================
```

One question only:
Why would you create the hyperlink to point to the same cell where it is?

Comment: i need to extend the range past 200. I tried to change what you originally wrote (Const cRow2 As Long = 200) to (Const cRow2 As Long = 800) and I get type error. Any idea why?

Comment: It works fine on my comp, but I noticed a case sensitivity problem with Title. It has to be written exactly like it is written in the cSearch variable. if you would like to send me the file I could look into it.

Comment: &vbasic2008 ive updated my original post with the script im working with. I get a type mismatch error, I also ensured my case sensitivity is the same, both are written as Title in proper format.

Answer (score 0):

you would need something like this

```
If titleDetailSheet.Range("B" & r) = searchString Then
    mainFile.ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add _
         Anchor:=titleDetailSheet.Range("B" & r + 1), _
         Address:="", _
         SubAddress:="'" & titleDetailSheet.Name & "'!" & titleDetailSheet.Range("B" & r).Address, _
         TextToDisplay:=titleDetailSheet.Range("B" & r + 1).Value
End If
```

Kindly see if you can understand the syntax and just ask me if there are unclear items. ^-^